# HTML5 image effects

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am working on converting a flash image editor into a html5 one. One of the editor features is applying effects on the image. Here is a screenshot of some of the effects that are available in the flash version: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0293dgfv8f

How do you achieve those effects? By changing the hue/saturation/brightness and contrast of the images? I am using pixastic library to manipulate the images so changing the values of hue/saturation etc is easy.

Unfortunately i know nothing about flash and looking into the source code of the flash editor gave me no hint.

I can start trying to manipulate those values and try to match the effect. I just wanna know if this is the right way, i dont want to waste any time by trying random values to get the desired effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at css filter. It has one downside and that is that is almost with no browser compactable.

You can also take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_filters_intro.asp

Comment: CSS doesent help so much. I need the effect to be applied to the canvas so i can export the result into an image format.

Comment: try javascript. maybe you can find a plugin that's made for image editing. take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247712/js-jquery-image-editor

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can do is use webGl and apply fullscreen shaders to get that effects. Css filters are just this.
Check this related question:
[webgl postprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652985/2d-image-processing-with-webgl)